# How to run unit tests for Android is not on the device or emulator?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, jvm, continuous-integration

In android studio in the new sub-project has, as I understand this integration tests that run on the device or emulator, checks the functionality of the application depends on the SDK android. But I do have methods do not depend on android. Their testing, I would like to spend on the JVM, avoiding run the emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of version 1.1.0 RC1 of Android Studio and the gradle plugin, you can run JUnit 4 unit tests on a JVM without the need of a device.

Take a look at this [post](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support)

If you have the latest version of Android Studio (1.1 and above) you do not need to worry about using the correct gradle plugin; it is already done. You still need to set that you want to use the experimental unit testing feature in `Settings > Gradle > Experimental.`

Comment: Thanks. And how to run these tests from the command line (gradle)?

Comment: you would do `./gradlew test`

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually trying to change my projects with MVP and unit test everything instead of using Espresso for testing the project.

I have a project with 160 tests with espresso and some idling resources and it takes like 20-30 minutes to run, and it turns to be expensive to run tests on aws farm or test droid ($5/run/device), so maybe there´s a hope with MVP and unit tests.

Take a look here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support

1. You can define a `app/src/test/java/<apk_package>/` folder and put all your JUnit 4 tests there and they will run without an emulator
2. Add the dependency: `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'`
3. Run tests :D

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, it is important to put the junit test files in the app/src/test/java/[apk_package]/ folder, not the app/src/androidTest/java/[apk_package]/ folder! Putting it in the androidTest folder will force run the android emulator or device runner.